# Profile image update fails using upload new image option

Tags: support, bug, profile-picture

I tried to upload a new profile picture on Stack Overflow. I selected an image, but when waiting for upload success, I got a crash report. However, I didn't get any details regarding the fail.

About a year ago I updated my profile image using the Gravtar option and the image was uploaded successfully.

I am on Windows 7 using the Mozilla Firefox browser and trying to upload a JPEG image. The image has 4928 x 3264 pixels and its size is 9.24 MB.

Why did the image upload fail? Could it be an image size or format issue?

Comment: That's a **huge** image for something that will end up in a 128*128 box. How about resizing it first to something more reasonable? I mean, even 1 MB is quite large given what it will end up as.

Comment: @Oded  Oh!! I didn't know that.. Its 4928x3264 pixels , so should I resize to 128x128 or compress for small size like (in KB) **but I suppose to get some error details regarding this. Right?** anyway Thank you so much I will try it again after a while.

Comment: Even 500*500 should be fine...

Comment: closing, looks like you've managed to change your picture

Comment: @m0sa that's by design, no bug was fixed here. (there's a dupe as well :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @Oded, I resized my image to thumbnail size of 128 x 128 pixels. Now the image size is 12 kB and I was able to change the picture successfully.

My understanding was, that image sizes up to 10 MB are accepted. Therefore, I don't understand why uploading failed for an image with 9.24 MB.

Anyway, I am grateful for the help provided by @Oded.

Comment: hi actuly am trying to change profie picture but after click on change picture on loading shows no any file selection dialog open.